# Android HoneyComb Registering Home Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, default, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-launcher

Last year I developed an app on a Xoom running Honeycomb 3.0. When running on that device the following code from the manifest worked.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
</intent-filter>
```

As you will know this registers my app (specifically, the Activity) to listen for "Home Intents." This worked fine and after the first time I could set my app as the default activity for this action.

Now I have installed the same app onto a Samsung Galaxy Tab running Honeycomb 3.1 and this functionality no longer works, no matter what state the app is in, or how many times it has been opened.

Is this intentional? Is this a Samsung only issue? Most importantly - can I regain the functionality I used to get on the Xoom?

P.S My app is completely legitimate in its intentions and has a perfectly understandable reason to want to replace the Home app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of:

```
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSER"/>
```

and see if that helps. Also, try the Home sample app found in your SDK. It uses the following `<intent-filter>`:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: If I remove LAUNCHER and BROWSER the app becomes invisible to "All Apps" (although I can still uninstall it) and the only way to run the Activity is by using 
`adb shell am start -n com.Example/com.Example.Activity`

At no point does pressing the Home button ask me if I would like to use my app.

I have looked through the samples too but not found anything.

Comment: @Edd: I don't mean "look at the Home sample app" -- I mean actually run it. If that fails, then there's some Samsung-specific problem for certain. If that works, though, then you have a basis for trying to determine where your setup differs from the working one.

Comment: I installed the sample home app, then I did `adb uninstall com.example.android.home` and everything now behaves as I expected, allowing me to chose between my app and the default Launcher app.

So, my app remains identical, but the process of installing and removing the sample home app has altered the behaviour of the device permanently (I have rebooted it) and now it behaves how I expect it to.

Confusing, but thanks for your help Mark - fixed! :)

Comment: @Edd: That's really bizarre. I'm glad it's working, but I'm seriously confused as to why...

Comment: If I had more time I would figure it out as I hate to leave gaps in my knowledge...however I have a dissertation to write, so I will just have to thank the little Androids for cooperating and for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to install, and then uninstall the sample Home app for Android 3.1.

Pressing home now allows a choice between my app and the default Launcher app.

My app remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on an `ASUS tablet`.  I believe the problem was because Launcher was set as the default app for the Home button (i.e., I pressed the home button, got the popup that asks which application I wanted to use, clicked the 'Use by default for this action' checkbox at the bottom of the pop-up, then chose Launcher).

You can fix the problem by going to `Settings->Applications`, choosing the Launcher, then clicking on the `Clear Defaults` button.

I gather the reason the sample Home app does the trick is because it clears the defaults itself (how, I don't know, but I know it's not done by setting categories in the intent-filter).